# Entity Framework 4.1. Loading navigational properties from Ids

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I have a bunch of properties like this on `OrderItem`:

```
        public virtual Frame Frame { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Frame")]
        public int? FrameId { get; set; }
```

I have a controller like this:

```
    public ActionResult CostOptions(OrderItem oi)
```

I am setting the Ids on `oi` with model binding as above, now is there a way to get the navigational properties to load automatically from the Ids? Do I need to insert the entity to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OrderItem` has to be a proxy created by EF inorder to load the navigational property pointed by the relevant id. Your current implementation does not allow this because MVC model binder creates the instance `OrderItem`.

```
public ActionResult CostOptions()
{
     // creates instance of the proxy
     var oi = db.OrderItems.Create();

     if (TryUpdateModel(oi))
     {
          // new entity has to be added before retrieving lazy loaded prop
          db.OrderItems.Add(oi);
          // lazy loaded property
          var frame = oi.Frame;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, but in my case oi is not yet in the database. I would prefer not to insert it at this stage if possible.

Comment: @Tom Edited my answer. You need to create the instance using `Create` method and `Add` it to `DbSet` before accessing navigational property.